# Using bash to query a large tab delimited file

Tags: bash, awk, grep, zip, zgrep

I have a list of names and IDs (50 entries)

`cat input.txt`

```
name    ID
Mike    2000
Mike    20003
Mike    20002
```

And there is a huge zipped file (13GB)

`zcat clients.gz`

```
name    ID  comment
Mike    2000    foo
Mike    20002   bar
Josh    2000    cake
Josh    20002   _
```

My expected output is

```
NR  name    ID  comment
1    Mike   2000    foo
3    Mike   20002   bar
```

each `$1"\t"$2` of clients.gz is a unique identifier. There might be some entries from `input.txt` that might be missing from `clients.gz`. Thus, I would like to add the NR column to my output to find out which are missing. I would like to use zgrep. awk takes a very long time (since I had to `zcat` for uncompress the zipped file I assume?)

I know that `zgrep 'Mike\t2000'` does not work. The NR issue I can fix with awk FNR I imagine.

So far I have:

```
awk -v q="'" 
'
NR > 1 {
print "zcat clients.gz | zgrep -w $" q$0q
}' input.txt |
bash > subset.txt
```

Comment: been thinking about this for a while. I mixed zgrep with awk and am running an array. Though am not sure if there is an easier way? I could not figure out how to do `zgrep '$Mike\t2002'`

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to print out the entries that aren't present in the clients file if that's what you're interested in?

Comment: @Shawn The comment column is what I am interested in and there are a few more things I simplified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
{ key = $1 FS $2 }
NR == FNR { map[key] = (NR>1 ? NR-1 : "NR"); next }
key in map { print map[key], $0 }

$ zcat clients.gz | awk -f tst.awk input.txt -
NR      name    ID      comment
1       Mike    2000    foo
3       Mike    20002   bar
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. It returns an empty output on the test files. Am trying to understand where it goes wrong

Comment: The usual suspect is DOS line endings. Try running dos2unix or similar on input.txt then run the command again. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/45772525/1745001 for more info on that issue. If it's not that that then make sure your fields in both files truly are tab-separated as you said they are.

Comment: I was dropping the hyphen mark; I fixed. What does it do?

Comment: The script? Creates a mapping of the 2 key fields to the line number from input.txt and then for every key field from clients.gz that exist in that map (i.e. were present in input.txt) prints the associated line number followed by the current line. Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: `zcat clients.gz | awk -f tst.awk input.txt -`  The hyphen after input.txt

Comment: Oh, in just about any UNIX tool `-` in place of a file name means "stdin" so that's what's telling awk to read the input comping from the `zcat ... |` pipeline after it reads input.txt. It's similar to `<(zcat clients.gz)` in Cyrus' script but not bash-specific.

Comment: took 20 mins and 2.5M memory. One last issue, how do I add the column names?

Comment: They should be printed by default (see the output in my answer). If they aren't then the first line of each file doesn't look like what you  showed in the example in your question.

Comment: something else came to my mind! `zcat file.gz | awk -f tst.awk input.txt` prints file.gz line by line and compares it with input.txt? Using <(zcat file.gz) <(cat input.txt) is memory intensive because it decompresses and prints file.gz and input to memory?

Comment: Not into memory but into temp files on your disk.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk and bash:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} 
     # process input.txt
     NR==FNR{
       a[$1,$2]=$1 FS $2
       line[$1,$2]=NR-1
       next
     }
     # process <(zcat clients.gz)
     {
       $4=a[$1,$2]
       if(FNR==1)
         line[$1,$2]="NR"
       if($4!="")
         print line[$1,$2],$1,$2,$3
     }' input.txt <(zcat clients.gz)
```

Output:

```
NR      name    ID      comment
1       Mike    2000    foo
3       Mike    20002   bar
```

---

As one line:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} NR==FNR{a[$1,$2]=$1 FS $2; line[$1,$2]=NR-1; next} {$4=a[$1,$2]; if(FNR==1) line[$1,$2]="NR"; if($4!="")print line[$1,$2],$1,$2,$3}' input.txt <(zcat clients.gz)
```

See: [Joining two files based on two key columns awk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/432115/joining-two-files-based-on-two-key-columns-awk) and [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Comment: would this be faster than zgrep?

Comment: I can't answer that question.

Comment: Thanks! this looks very clean with NR-1. I assume it writes the input file which is small into memory (loop through the first section), then scans the second file (zcat clients.gz)

Comment: Yes, `NR==FNR{...; next}` loops only through first file and reads column 1 and 2 in array `A` and current line number to array `line`. Second section loops then only through the second "file" and checks if there is a match in array A.

Comment: Per [this item](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Reference-to-Elements.html#Reference-to-Elements) ... isn't `$4=a[$1,$2]` going to create an array element for each row produced by `zcat clients.gz`? wouldn't `if ( ($1 FS $2) in a)` require less memory?

Comment: @markp yes, as written `a[]` would end up with an entry for every unique $1,$2 combination in the file that's 13GB **when compressed**.

Comment: @EdMorton thanks, I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something esoteric between a) array reference as a test (the exchange you and I had yesterday) and b)  array reference in an assignment

Comment: By assigning to a field ($4) it will also force awk to recompile every line that's read so using a variable instead of $4 would also be more efficient.

Comment: This took ~ 30 mins with a max memory was 62GB

Comment: @user171558 did you test the other solutions posted? How long and how much memory did they take?

Answer (score 1):

**[EDIT]**
I've misunderstood where the prepended line numbers come from. Corrected.

Would you try the following:

```
declare -A num          # asscoiates each pattern to the line number
mapfile -t ary < <(tail -n +2 input.txt)
pat=$(IFS='|'; echo "${ary[*]}")
for ((i=0; i<${#ary[@]}; i++)); do num[${ary[i]}]=$((i+1)); done
printf "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n" "NR" "name" "ID" "comment"
zgrep -E -w "$pat" clients.gz | while IFS= read -r line; do
    printf "%d\t%s\n" "${num[$(cut -f 1-2 <<<"$line")]}" "$line"
done
```

Output:

```
NR  name    ID  comment
1   Mike    2000    foo
3   Mike    20002   bar
```

- The second line and third generate a search pattern as `Mike  2000|Mike       20003|Mike      20002` from `input.txt`.
- The line `for ((i=0; i<${#ary[@]}; i++)); do ..` creates a map from
  the pattern to the number.
- The expression `"${num[$(cut -f 1-2 <<<"$line")]}"` retrieves the line
  number from the 1st and 2nd fields of the output.

If the performance is not still satisfactory, please consider `ripgrep` which is much faster than `grep` or `zgrep`.